# AAB: Installing Google Play Console APK, but app has a small update?

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I recently uploaded an update to my app using Android App Bundle, where I had previously updated it using APKs.  What I forgot is that I need a signed version of the APK for a few people who can't update through the Play Store.  I used to do this by just using adb commands to pull the APK from a device after updating it in the Play Store, but with AAB there are 3 APKs (1 base, 1 language, 1 screen density), so I can no longer do that.  I let Google sign it with a different signing key than the one I have in Android Studio, so I can't just generate an APK from there with the same signing key.

I did find that in the Play Console, I can download a "Signed, Universal APK" which seems to work without an issue.  What's odd is that when I install that APK, there is an update for the app in the Play Store (59 kB in size, compared to the 5 MB APK).  What could be in that 59 kB update?

Comment: Could be a lot of things. You might want to analyze the apks using android studio and see if you can find a difference.  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer

Comment: Yeah but there are 3 APKs for the AAB, so can't really compare two APKs.